# How do I show that $e^{x+1} > 2x + 2$ for all $x>0$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Hello I would need help to solve the equation above.
So far I have tried letting $$f(x) = e^{x+1}- 2x -2$$

$$f'(x)= e^{x+1} -2$$

$$e^ {x+1} > 2$$

$$x> \ln 2-1$$

but I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Find the derivative and comment about monotonocity

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you wrote. Notice that $\ln 2 - 1<0$. You have shown that $f'(x) > 0$ when $x > \ln 2 - 1$. Now calculate $f(0)$. As long as this is positive, you are done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: at $x=0$,
\begin{align}
e^{1+x}&=e \text{ and } 2x+2=2 \, .
\end{align}
Then argue that the gradient of $e^{1+x}$ is greater than that of $2x+2$ for $x\geq0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t) = e^{t}- 2t$

You have to show that $f(t) > 0$ for $t>1.$

We have

$$f(1)=e-2>0$$

and

$$f'(t)=e^t-2 >e-2>0$$

for $t>1.$

Hence $f$ is strictly increasing on $[1,\infty).$ Thus $f(t)>f(1)>0$ for $t>1.$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the known inequality $e^x > x+1$.
Multiplying by $e$:  $e^{x+1}> ex+e$.
Now, I would like to use that $e>2$ to conclude, but maybe $x+1<0$. However, in this case, since $exp$ is a positive function, the inequality holds anyways, so I can conclude in the following way:

If $x+1 < 0$, then since $e^{x+1}>0$, we have $e^{x+1}>2x+2$.

In the other case, $2x+2<ex+e<e^{x+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using familiar properties of $e^x$, namely  $e\gt2$, $\int e^udu=e^u+C$, and $e^x\ge1$ for $x\ge0$, we have

$$e^{x+1}=e(e^x-1)+e\gt2\int_0^xe^u\,du+2\ge2\int_0^xdu+2=2x+2$$